# Fail to create variable using eval in Node.js ES6

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, eval, mjs

It seems not possible to create a variable using `eval` in Node.js ES6 but I can't understand why. This happens to me on CentOS 7, but I don't believe OS is the problem here.

Regular Node.js file (test.js):

```
eval("var a=1");
console.log(a);
```

Make the same file with .mjs extension to run with Node.js ES6 (test.mjs):

```
eval("var a=1");
console.log(a);
```

After that, run the 2 files with Node.js, and Node.js ES6:

```
$ node test.js
1

$ node --experimental-modules test.mjs
(node:9966) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
ReferenceError: a is not defined
    at file:///temp/test.mjs:2:13
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:96:12)
```

Is it an issue related to ES6? I tried on browser's console and the problem is the same:

```
>> eval("var a=1"); console.log(a);
   1

>> class c { static f(){ eval("var a=1"); console.log(a); } }
   c.f()
   ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

I'm using Node.js 10.9.0, is it a bug or there's a reason behind it?

Comment: It's probably a scoping issue. The scope of the variable is just within `eval`.

Comment: it's global scope, only 2 lines of code

Comment: I suspect when you enable modules, scoping rules change.

Comment: i still dont get it, the 'eval' and the 'console.log' are in the same scope, aren't they?

Comment: I'm suggesting that `eval` creates a nested scope for the expressions being executed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In strict mode, variables created inside an `eval()` statement are available only to that code.  It does not create new variables in your local scope (here's a [good article](http://whereswalden.com/2011/01/10/new-es5-strict-mode-support-new-vars-created-by-strict-mode-eval-code-are-local-to-that-code-only/) on the topic) whereas it can create variables in the local scope when not in strict mode.

And, mjs modules run in strict mode by default.  A regular node.js script file is not in strict mode by default.  So, the difference in strict mode setting causes a difference in behavior of `eval()`.

Comment: @Barmar - Yes, I was confirming that before writing it, and have now added it to my answer.

Comment: ic, mjs and browser es6 run in strict mode by default, and variables created in eval in strict mode won't be available outside, tks

Comment: @jfriend00, any workaround to create variable in local scope? i can't think of anything else rather than eval, but i must use es6 class.

Comment: @datdinhquoc - You'd have to show us what real coding problem you're actually trying to solve.  Usually, the solution is to not actually create local variables, but to create a base object and then dynamically add properties to that object.  That can be done with normal Javascript, even in strict mode.

Comment: @jfriend00, tks, i'm now using the object.property solution, adding properties to object. eval to create variables is evil sometimes, it may break code if the being created variable is already in the code

Answer (score 1):

With the answer from @jfriend00 and from my testing:

Calling `eval` directly doesn't work in es6 class or .mjs file:

```
eval("var a=1");
console.log(a);
```

However, calling `eval` INDIRECTLY does work in es6 class or .mjs file:

```
var geval = eval;
geval("var a=1");
console.log(a);
```

Comment: tks for the report, i haven't tested on nodejs 12 or node-nightly